# Pandas Resampling Code Runs extremely Slowly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to resample some data in Pandas and I am using the code below:

On my data it takes, `5 hours`.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('date')
df.groupby('id').resample('D')['value'].agg('sum').loc[lambda x: x>0]
```

This is prohibitively slow.

How can I speed up the above code, on data like:

```
id    date    value

1   16-12-1     9
1   16-12-1     8
1   17-1-1      18
2   17-3-4      19
2   17-3-4      20
1   17-4-3      21
2   17-7-13     12
3   17-8-9      12
2   17-9-12     11
1   17-11-12    19
3   17-11-12    21

giving output:

id  date      
1   2016-12-04    17
    2017-01-01    18
    2017-04-09    21
    2017-11-12    19
2   2017-03-05    39
    2017-07-16    12
    2017-09-17    11
3   2017-08-13    12
    2017-11-12    21
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

I set up date as an index but the code is so slow. Any help would be great.

Comment: How large is your data?

Comment: @Tabbakhh 12 million rows

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try. 
I am going to use `pd.Grouper()` and specify the frequency to daily, hoping that it is faster. Also, i am getting rid of the `agg` and using `.sum()` straight away.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('date')
df2 = df.groupby(['id',pd.Grouper(freq='D')])['value'].sum()
```

Results:

```
id  date      
1   2016-12-01    17
    2017-01-01    18
    2017-04-03    21
    2017-11-12    19
2   2017-03-04    39
    2017-07-13    12
    2017-09-12    11
3   2017-08-09    12
    2017-11-12    21
```

Hope this works.

[EDIT]

So I just did a small test between both methods over a randomly generated df with 100000 rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 30,size=100000),
                  columns=["id"],
                  index=pd.date_range("19300101", periods=100000))
df['value'] = np.random.randint(0, 10,size=100000)
```

and tried it on both codes and the results are:

for using `resmple`:

```
startTime = time.time()
df2 = df.groupby('id').resample('D')['value'].agg('sum').loc[lambda x: x>0]
print(time.time()-startTime)
1.0451831817626953 seconds
```

for using `pd.Grouper()`:

```
startTime = time.time()
df3 = df.groupby(['id',pd.Grouper(freq='D')])['value'].sum()
print(time.time()-startTime)
0.08430838584899902 seconds
```

so approximately **12 times faster!** (if my math is correct)

Comment: @Jondiedoop - was already working on it, but I was busy and just finished it! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I also do believe that getting rid of redundant methods such as `.loc` with the lambda helps in reducing the time